# How to make list of divs into carousel by 4 columns in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

Can anyone help me turn the below html codes into carousel by 4 columns? that would look something like this screenshot? hopefully in javascript or jquery?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKxgR.png)

```
<div class="carousel">
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Try this: https://codepen.io/mephysto/pen/ZYVKRY
For multiple divs in carousel.

Comment: Thank you @MuhammadHuzaifa will try that one.

Comment: Hi @MuhammadHuzaifa can I ask where to change if I want to make into 4 columns? tried changing the col-xs-4 to col-xs-3, but there are only 3 images displaying. Thank you

Comment: Need to add another image using `append` property in javascript. like following:

`next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));`